# Magento 2, link is not working, images are not loading

Tags: javascript, css, magento, hyperlink, magento2

**running from xampp apache server**
installation was successfull, login is working but whenever i'm trying to configure backend configuration it's not working

[image: interface is like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you

Goto Magento 2 `root directory -> pub -> static`

Remove static folder and remove `var/cache`, `var/composer_home`, `var/generation`, `var/page_cache`, `var/view_preprocessed`

Then run,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```